# Program Finding Duplicate Strings in a List of Strings

Tags: c, string, duplicates

I'm trying to write a program that compares strings input by the user. I already can find the longest string and the "max" (largest ASCII code for first nonequal character), but I can't figure out how to find the first instance of a duplicate string out of the list. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char words[50], max[50], longest[50], dupe[50];
        int n, c, x, dupepos;
        dupe[0] = '\0';
        max[0] = '\0';
        longest[0] = '\0';
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(c = 0; c <= n; c++) {
                fgets(words, 50, stdin);
                x = strcmp(max, words);
                if(strlen(words) > strlen(longest)) strcpy(longest, words);
                if(x < 0) strcpy(max, words);
        }
        printf("Longest: %s", longest);
        printf("Max: %s", max);
//      if(dupe == 0) printf("UNIQUE (no dupes)\n");
//      else printf("First dupe found at position %d: %s\n", dupepos, dupe);
        return 0;
}
```

I commented out the if statement for displaying the duplicate as it won't work currently. I can do this same program for integers using an array such as:

```
for(int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
    scanf("%d", &num);
    unique[num]++;
    if(unique[num] > 1 && dupe == 0) dupe = num;
}
```

I would basically like to do the same with a list of strings. If there is an easier way to accomplish my task that would be welcomed!

If the test file looked like this:

```
7
The first line
fun
let x be 19
8 > 3
bracket
fun
Turkey
```

It should output this:

```
Longest: The first line
Max: let x be 19
First dupe found at position 6: fun
```

If the test file looked like this:

```
5
The first line
let x be 19
8 > 3
{bracket}
turkey
```

It should output this:

```
Longest: The first line
Max: {bracket}
UNIQUE (no dupes)
```

Comment: You need to save all the lines in an array. Then after reading each line, go through the array looking for a duplicate.

Comment: Your code reads `n+1` strings.

Comment: If strings are stored in an array (e.g. `char words[MAX][50];`), then you could do the following: sorting the array (e.g. with `qsort()`) and, afterwards, loop through this array (beginning by 1) comparing each element with its predecessor (e.g. with `strcmp())`. After sorting, duplicates should be be "neighbours". I would expect for `qsort()` O(ld N) and the loop to search for duplicates is O(N). So, O((ld N) + N) sounds more friendly than the O(N²) which would result from the naive approach: two nested loops where the 1st is tested against the rest, the 2nd against the rest, and so on.

Comment: @Scheff I need to be able to index the position of the appearance of the first duplicate as well so sorting it would break that part.

Comment: I was not aware of this requirement. This could be handled storing the original line no. together with string (e.g. in a struct). It's a little bit more effort but still possible with my `qsort()` idea. If you think it's too complicated you can fall back to the naive approach. O(N²) is not that terrible on a modern CPU for not too big Ns. ;-)